How to select part of the text when using TINYMCE Non Editable FullScreen?
In a certain module of my application, due to business needs, the TinyMCE editor is configured as non-editable. However, the user needs to select only part of the TEXT displayed in the editor and not its complete content. The TinyMCE Editor is being used in conjunction with the EXTJs 3.4.0 library.
Can someone help me?
Below is an example of how it is implemented in the application:
settings_TINYMCE_NonEditableFullScreen = { 
   language:'pt', 
   mode:'specific_textareas',
   theme:'advanced', 
   readonly:false,
   plugins:'noneditable,fullscreen', 
   theme_advanced_buttons1:'fullscreen',
   theme_advanced_toolbar_location:'top', 
   theme_advanced_toolbar_align:'left', 
   theme_advanced_statusbar_location:'',
   theme_advanced_resizing:true,
   toolbar_items_size:'small', 
   nowrap:false,
   keep_styles:true,
   cleanup_on_startup:true,
   fix_nesting:true,
   fix_list_elements:true,
   fix_table_elements:true, 
   noneditable_noneditable_class:'TinyMCENonEditable',
   noneditable_leave_contenteditable:true,
   fullscreen_new_window:true, 
   fullscreen_settings:{content_editable:false},
   min_width:200, 
   min_height:200,
   theme_advanced_fonts : 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=couriernew,courier,monospace;Ecológica=SpranqecosansRegular;Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;Verdana=verdana,geneva'
 }

settings_TEXTAREA_TINYMCE_Ementa = {};
Ext.apply(settings_TEXTAREA_TINYMCE_Ementa, settings_TINYMCE_NonEditableFullScreen);

TEXTAREA_TINYMCE_Ementa = { 
      itemId:'TEXTAREA_TINYMCE_Ementa', 
      xtype:'tinymce', 
      ref:'editor',
      value:'', 
      tinymceSettings:settings_TEXTAREA_TINYMCE_Ementa,
      height:TEXTAREATINYMCEHeight,
      autoShow:true, 
      columnWidth:.76 };

